# Idiot Check: Is this a good way to do track all the (python) classes I use?

Tags: python-3.x

**Me**:  fairly new to python, old hand with OOP in PHP and JavaScript

**The Project**:  Game.  Also most complicated project I've ever attempted.

Will have maps that contain locations that contain characters and items that may have inventories of even more items. Each such item will be an object that has a unique id and may or may not be from a unique class.

Dynamic data for each of these objects will be stored in a sqlite3 database.

**The Problem**:

I can't store the actual objects or classes themselves in the database, so once an object is unloaded (no longer needed or the game itself is terminated), I will need to reconstruct the object from its original class... which means I need a way to access just about any class in the game on the fly, based only on what's stored in the database.

**The Solution**:

Keep a dictionary of all possible object classes, keyed by name, and store the class name of all active classes in the database, so when reloading an object I can just use

```
loadeditem = classDict['DoriaTheTrollslayer']( [constructor parameters] )
```

instead of

```
import universeObjects.Characters.npcs.DoriaTheTrollSlayer as DoriaTheTrollSlayer
loadeditem = DoriaTheTrollslayer( [constructor parameters] )
```

The latter being particularly unappealing because I won't know what to import.

**The Implementation:**

Make each map a package, which contains simple locations (few or no characters/items present) as modules, and more complicated locations as packages.

Use **init**.py for each package to a) create a dictionary of classes that are defined within that package, b) import nested packages, and c) import the class dictionary of the nested packages into its own dictionary.

This solution allows me to make separate dictionaries at the package level, where they are easy to maintain, and still end up with one final merged dictionary, where it is easy to use.

**For Example**

```
\CityMap
   __init__.py
   Mainstreet.py
   Broadstreet.py
   Elmstreet.py
   \StopAndSlop
      __init__.py
      StopAndSlopStore.py
      JaneTheBarista.py
      JoanTheBarista.py
      BobTheCreepyCustomer.py

CityMap.StopAndSlop.__init__.py:
   from CityMap.StopAndSlop.StopAndSlopStore import StopAndSlopStore
   from CityMap.StopAndSlop.JaneTheBarista import JaneTheBarista
   from CityMap.StopAndSlop.JoanTheBarista import JoanTheBarista
   from CityMap.StopAndSlop.BobTheCreepyCustomer import BobTheCreepyCustomer
   classDict={}
   classDict[ 'StopAndSlopStore' ] = StopAndSlopStore
   classDict[ 'JaneTheBarista' ] = JaneTheBarista
   classDict[ 'JoanTheBarista' ] = JoanTheBarista
   classDict[ 'BobTheCreepyCustomer' ] = BobTheCreepyCustomer

CityMap.__init__.py
   from CityMap.Mainstreet import Mainstreet
   from CityMap.Broadstreet import Broadstreet
   from CityMap.Elmstreet import Elmstreet
   classDict={}
   classDict[ 'Mainstreet' ] = Mainstreet
   classDict[ 'Broadstreet' ] = Broadstreet
   classDict[ 'Elmstreet' ] = Elmstreet

   import CityMap.StopAndSlop
   classDict.update( CityMap.StopAndSlop.classDict )
```

**The Question:**

Is this as good an solution/implementation as I think it is?

Comment: *"being particularly unappealing because I won't know what to import"*. Why not just always import everything that might be needed? The mere act of importing functionality should not chew up your memory, regardless of the project size.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but you can open other python files into your current one, which allows you to run classes from other python files. sorry if you already know this and it doesn't work for you...

Comment: I think that your implementation is OK. But I'm not sure if this question is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here - opinion based questions are usually closed.